# Service discoverability in SOA

Tags: web-services, soa

I was reading a slide about the SOA. And was having doubt at this point:

```
Discoverability is beyond the scope of a Web Service
```

Does it mean that, the webservice doesn't take care of the discovery part? I mean the service providers submits their webservice to service registry so that the clients could discover it, isn't it? Is that what it meant by that point?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are talking about the possibility to discover a service between a service registry (ie: UDDI), that's right, the service doesn't need to know anything about the discoverability part. But keep in mind that the service has a contract which exposes his metadata and this is the data published to the service registry. 
Graphic description:
[image]

Check this note extracted from a post from Michael Poulin, it's what i was trying to explain at first.

> Talking now about Service Discoverability principle, I can witness
>   that this is the only one principle that survived the time and has not
>   significantly changed. Thomas Erl says about this principle: 'This
>   service-orientation principle is related to, but distinct from,
>   discoverability on an architectural level ... On a service level, the
>   principle of discoverability refers to the design of an individual
>   service so that it becomes as discoverable as possible, regardless of
>   whether a discoverability product or extension actually exists in its
>   surrounding implementation environment'.
>
> The principle definition nicely points to two things that are very
>   important to the service discovering: supplemented meta-data and
>   meta-data by which the service may be effectively interpreted. I am
>   re-phrasing the principle to point to a meta-data document
>   supplementing a service and to a registry/repository of such
>   documents. While registry/repository is an element of infrastructure
>   and may be absent, the supplementing meta-data document is due. OASIS
>   SOA RM standard identifies such document as 'service description'.
>   [Michael Poulin](http://www.ebizq.net/blogs/service_oriented/2009/02/evolution_of_principles_of_service_orientation_service_composability_and_discoverability_part_7.php)

Comment: This is all true, except for the fact that almost nobody uses UDDI at all, certainly not public UDDI registries. It was a good idea whose time  never came.

Comment: @JohnSaunders completely agree. The idea of a service discovery mechanism is still fully valid, ie: Netflix Curator (now moved to Apache) http://curator.apache.org/curator-x-discovery/index.html

Comment: I've been doing SOA for a while now, and never had a need to "discover" a service. If I don't know about the service, then why am I calling it? And why don't we already know where it is located? If we move services around, then we simply need a mechanism to manage the change in service URLs. That doesn't require a discovery mechanism.

Comment: Well, i think it depends on the size and nature of your architecture, in some cases it's impossible to go on without having a service discovery mechanism, an excellent description of real cases in: http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/02/04/service-discovery-in-the-cloud/

Comment: Sorry, still haven't seen the case where load balancing doesn't work. I know of cases that use a simple service location mechanism where the client looks up the endpoint to use based on certain criteria, but a full "service _discovery_" mechanism - no. That article seems to presuppose the need for discovery.

Comment: I am not trying to convince you, it just depends on the scenario you are dealing with :) Just another interesting case to read: http://nerds.airbnb.com/smartstack-service-discovery-cloud/

Comment: Thank you. Just another doubt, can we call all SOA applications as a BPEL application too? I mean BPEL applications means, we compose two or more services together isn't it? So is it correct?

Comment: Well BPEL is an orchestration language (so it's a way to compose services) that helps defining business process (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language). Service composition is one of the most important features of SOA, you reuse another services when performing a composition.